# Laravel database still use old name after .env changed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Edit:
php artisan config:cache work nice, but now I got other problem.
the URL giving me Error 500

I upload a project to a new subdomain area after I changed .env file 
when I open URL I still got an error with the old database and user

[image: error screen shoot]

I tried to check online with the .env file but - I don't know where he stored this database, I tried to see where is this name with ctrl+f but - nothing found

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=faceterc_hot
DB_USERNAME=faceterc_hot
DB_PASSWORD=testpro
```

I expect to get the same error maybe but not with the old database name.
and this gives me a indicate that maybe the file or something not changed or he using the other details from I don't know where

Comment: Welcome. In order to get help you are going to need to improve your question. Please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please share your layout blade.

Comment: hey i added a picture of the problem. the wired thing is i didnt edited  public/index.php

Comment: You may need to build your styles by running `npm run prod` or `npm run dev`.

Comment: @ElroyCohen Please check if it is having any old values in `config/database.php`

Comment: try `artisan config:cache`

Comment: restart php artisan serve

Answer (score 4):

Good, practice for, If you change in a .env file first restart the server using below command.

`php artisan serve`

then after run below more command for clear old cache and config.

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: i tried this, now i got :SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do a

```
php artisan config:cache
```

In case you are on a shared hosting, you can change the values in `config/database.php` to only use the set values in your `.env`. Setting it like this will make sure, it only use the `.env` values.

```
mysql' => [
'driver'    => 'mysql',
'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix'    => '',
'strict'    => false, 
],
```

Comment: hope its more clear now, the problem it's more than that :S

Comment: @ElroyCohen Add the user faceterc_hot to the database faceterc_hot

Comment: @ElroyCohen can you check you config/database.php file if it is holding any old values?

Answer (score 1):

php artisan config:clear Solve the problem with DATABASE error
just ran :
php artisan config:clear
with ssh at the main folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute

`php artisan config:cache`

as the laravel cache's the environment files rather than accessing the data from it on every request.

Comment: its work i think. but now i got error 500 - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good practice to run these couple of commands when you change any environment related variable:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

Execute these commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan optimize
```

That will clear your env cache and it should do.

Comment: `config:cache` is likely the only thing he needs to do